# ActiveModel::AttributeMethods Practicality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What situations would a developer come across where the rails AttributeMethodsPrefix and suffix methods are ideal to be used in. 
The below is taken directly from the Rails source and I'm still not sure of the practicality of them.

```
  #   class Person
  #     include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  #
  #     attr_accessor :name
  #     attribute_method_suffix '_short?'
  #     define_attribute_methods :name
  #
  #     private
  #
  #     def attribute_short?(attr)
  #       send(attr).length < 5
  #     end
  #   end
  #
  #   person = Person.new
  #   person.name = 'Bob'
  #   person.name          # => "Bob"
  #   person.name_short?   # => true
```

Thanks for your helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is used for example to provide the `<attribute>_changed?` method, and other helpers from [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html)

How you might use it in your code is up to you. You could easily provide `email_taken?`, `username_taken?` methods with this approach, to check if a user-entered email or username is still available.

I'd say you can consider using it when you want to know something about several attributes of your model (or maybe across models).

The example you posted does not really make sense to me, since it is only used for one attribute. Had they built the example with `:first_name` and `:last_name`, it would be clearer that you can construct reusable helper methods, that need to be defined only once.